# html issues when trying to renders columns

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

Not to sure why my my products are like this. They are out of order and displaced and looks ugly. The project is in bootstrap 3. Heres the image of how it looks:

[image]

The code below is in a partial

```
<% products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading preview">
                <%= image_tag product.cover_photo(:medium) %>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <%= link_to product.name, product %><br/>
                $<%= product.price %> - <%= product.weight %><br/>
                <%= product.strain_type %><br/>
                <%= product.product_type %><br/>
                <span style="color: red;">THC: <%= product.percentage %>%</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    $('#star_<%= product.id %>').raty({
        path: '/assets',
        readOnly: true,
        score: <%= product.average_rating %>
      });
</script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is the issue? How are you wanting it to look?

Comment: did you see the image above? There should be 3 products a row

Comment: Looks like there are 3 products in a row..

Comment: Can you post your CSS syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Set a fixed height to your panel

```
.panel-default {
   height: 200px; /* sample height */
}
```

It displays like that because of unequal height